# How can i get javascript variable from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have next code block:

```
$.post('page.php', function(data)
{
    //data - full page info
});
```

Returned data is html markup. And in this html i have javascript section with array:

```
var someArray= new Array();
```

How can i get this array object from data object?

**Edit:**

I cannot change data which returned from page.php. And basically this javascript just plugin to change existing page UI from other website. So i know that page contains array and i need get data from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work fine just append it to the body, then read in the variable.

See below:

http://jsfiddle.net/6CJUy/

Comment: I will read this page few times with different params. So i cannot every time just append it? Or i need to have some namespaces or what?

Comment: ok ... have a div #holder ... and then just run $('#holder').html(RESPONSE)  .... and then read the value ..

Comment: What you mean read? How can i access it in javascript when i added this to holder?

Comment: $('#holder').html() or $('#holder').innerHTML

Comment: It will be just text. So i need to parse it?

Comment: Dear Evgeny .. try it see what happens

Comment: Added those $('#holder').html(RESPONSE) and my javascript was rewrited by the same from page. And also i need to load page few temes. how can $('#holder').html() solves the issue?